# Using double integral to find the volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the region R of space bounded by the planes $x = 0, x = 3, z = 0,$ and the hyperbolic paraboloid $z = x^{2} - y^{2}$. $z=x^{2} - y^{2} = 0 <=> y = \pm x$.

So I got this solution from my book's answer key:

(1) $V = Vol(R) = \iint_D (x^{2}-y^{2})dA$

(2) $V= \int_{x=0}^{3} (\int_{y=-x}^{x}(x^{2}-y^{2})dy)dx$

(3) $V = \int_{x=0}^{3} (2\int_{y=0}^{x}(x^{2}-y^{2})dy)dx$ and so on...

My problem is how did the $y=-x$ on the inner integral on equation 2 turn into $y = 0$ and where did the $2$ outside the integral come from? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice that the integral is an even function as $x$ and $y$ are both squares, hence you can halve the interval of the integral and then double the integral.

Comment: @Mattos So you're basically solving the first half and doubling it to get the whole region?

Comment: @Mattos Why does it matter that x and y are both squares? I can still do the same even if the equation is $xy$ right?

Comment: As a little guide, why don't you graph $\cos(x)$ from $-2\pi$ to $2\pi$, just so you can get a feel for what it means to be an even function ($\cos(x)$ is even). Then integrate $\cos(x)$ twice; once from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the other time double the integral and integrate from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. It might help your understanding for the question you asked about.

Comment: @Mattos I think I understand that part. But does it also answer my second question about x and y being both squares?

Comment: Well, if $f(x)=x$ and $g(y)=y$, then both $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are _odd_ functions, and the multiplication of two _odd_ functions is an _even_ function. So yes, it would work. Note that the definition of an odd function in multivariables is $f(-x_1,-x_2,..,-x_n)=-f(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$ and definition of even function is $f(-x_1,-x_2,..,-x_n)=f(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$. So yes, the $xy$ case still holds and is an even function.

Comment: @Mattos Can you please give an example where I cannot do the same process as done in the solutions? Also, is the purpose of determining if the functions are even or odd is so that it can be determined if the functions are symmetrical or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in response to the OP's last question in the comments section.

An example where halving the interval length and doubling the integral *would not work* is when the function being integrated is *not* **even**, i.e when the function is either **odd** or **neither odd nor even**.

For example

$$\int_{-1}^{1} x^{6} dx = 2\int_{0}^{1}x^6 dx $$

as $x^{6}$ is an **even** function.

However,

$$\int_{-1}^{1} x^{5} dx = 0 \ne \frac{1}{3} =2\int_{0}^{1} x^5dx $$

as $x^{5}$ is an **odd** function.

Also, remember that halving the interval and doubling only works when you have a *symmetric* interval, ie when integrating over a region $[-a,a]$.